# In member function I get the error " invalid use of undefined type 'struct (name)' - forward declaration of 'struct (name)' "

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration, member-functions

I have the following files in the same project.
Don't bother reading all the blocks of code if you think it's not necessary, 
the error messages appear only in the ship.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "chart.cpp"
#define N 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j, flagi=-3, flagj=-3;
    int test, ports_count=0, treas_count=0;

    chart ***mapp;
    mapp=new chart **[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){mapp[i]=new chart *[N];}

     /*missing code initilazing chart ***mapp */

    return 0;
}
```

chart.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ship.cpp"

using namespace std;

class chart{

  bool isPort;
  int weather;
  int treasure;
  ship* shipPtr;

  public:
    chart(){isPort=false; weather=0; treasure=0; shipPtr=NULL;}

    bool getPort(){return isPort;}
    int getWeather(){return weather;}
    int getTreasure(){return treasure;}
    ship* getShip(){return shipPtr;}

    void setPort(bool port){isPort=port;}
    void setWeather(int weath){weather=weath;}
    void setTreasure(int treas){treasure=treas;}
    void setShip(ship* shp){shipPtr=shp;}
};
```

and 
ship.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 10

using namespace std;

class ship{
protected:
      string name;
      int maxhp, curhp, speed, curtreas, x_pos, y_pos;

public:
   friend class chart; 
   //the line above gives error message " forward declaration of 'struct chart' "

   static int shipcount;

   ship(){shipcount++;}

   string getName(){return name;}
   int getMaxhp(){return maxhp;}
   int getCurhp(){return curhp;}
   int getSpeed(){return speed;}
   int getCurtreas(){return curtreas;}
   int getX_pos(){return x_pos;}
   int getY_pos(){return y_pos;}

   bool Move(chart ***mapp){

      int x, y, blocked=0;

      for(x=x_pos-1;x<=x_pos+1;x++){
          if((x>-1) && (x<N)){
              for(y=y_pos-1;y<=y_pos+1;y++){
                   if((y>-1) && (y<N)){

/* the line below gives error message "invalid use of undefined type 'struct chart'"*/

                         if((!mapp[x][y]->getPort) && (mapp[x][y]->getShip==NULL)){
                                                   blocked++;
                         }
                   }
               }
          }
      }
      if(blocked<2){
          return false;
      }

      /* missing the rest of the body of bool Move cause it is too big */

    }
}
```

The compiler gives the following error messages:

```
"invalid use of undefined type 'struct chart' " in ship.cpp -> line 39

"forward declaration of 'struct chart' " in ship.cpp -> line 12
```

Why are these errors showing up?

I know the code is probably complex but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this code does not compile is that your `ship.cpp` file needs a definition of `chart` class in order to use its members. You fail to provide this definition, prompting the compiler to complain.

Since all of the members of class `chart` are defined in the class declaration, you can rename `chart.cpp` to `chart.h`, and add an `#include` for it in your `ship.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "chart.h"
#define N 10
... // The rest of ship.cpp code
```

Also replace the name `chart.cpp` in your `main` with `chart.h`.

Comment: I renamed chart.cpp to chart.h, included chart.h to ship.cpp and also replaced the chart.cpp with chart.h in main, but when trying to compile with these changes, compiling goes on without stopping and aftes a few seconds it crashes.

Comment: The compiler shows up the messages:

'In file included from ship.cpp:2    from chart.h

        from chart.h:2               from ship.cpp

        from ship.cpp:2              from chart.h
        from chart.h:2               from ship.cpp'

These messages continue to appear too many times and the is a message saying:

'#include nested deeply'

Comment: @thomas_p You need to replace `#include "ship.cpp"` in `chart.h` with a forward declaration `class ship;`

Comment: Well, I removed `#include "ship.cpp"` from `chart.h` and instead added a `class ship;` in `chart.h` as you said.
Then included `chart.h` to `ship.cpp` file and finally included only `ship.cpp` into `main.cpp`.
And after these changes the code got compiled! Thank you very much for your help.
Shall I post here any other questions I may have later or open a new question?